# JavaScript Object defineProperties and max

Tags: javascript, oop, getter-setter

I'm learning the basics of OOP in JavaScript and I'm having some issues with this example:

```
var Human = function (first, surname) {
    var x = {};
    Object.defineProperties(x, {
        first: {
            get: function () {
                return this.first;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.first = value;
            }
        },
        surname: {
            get: function () {
                return this.surname;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.surname = value;
            }
        }
    });
    return x;
};
var alex = new Human("Alex", "Corlette");
```

1. This: `console.log(alex);` Outputs:

   > { }
2. And this: `console.log(alex.first);` Outputs:

   > Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the scope. Since you are defining a property and in the getter and setter referencing to those same getters and setters.

The example could be fixed by removing the this keyword.

```
var Human = function (first, surname) {
  var x = {};
  Object.defineProperties(x, {
    first: {
        get: function () {
            return first;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            first = value;
        }
    },
    surname: {
        get: function () {
            return surname;
        },
        set: function (value) {
           surname = value;
        }
    }
  });
  return x;
};
var alex = new Human("Alex", "Corlette");
```